# How to simplify this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, button, hide, show, simplify

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
// for some reason the button hide has to be at the top
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".holcomb, .lunden, .maggie, .rosewood").hide("slow");
    $("button").hide("fast");
});
 // examples show hide
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#holcomb").click(function () {
       $(".holcomb, .lunden, .maggie, .rosewood").hide("fast");
       $("button").hide("fast")
       $(".holcomb").slideDown(1500);
       $("button#holcomb").show("fast")
   });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#lunden").click(function () {
        $(".holcomb, .lunden, .maggie, .rosewood").hide("fast");
        $("button").hide("fast")
        $(".lunden").slideDown(1500);
        $("button#lunden").show("fast")
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#maggie").click(function () {
        $(".holcomb, .lunden, .maggie, .rosewood").hide("fast");
        $("button").hide("fast")
        $(".maggie").slideDown(1500);
        $("button#maggie").show("fast")
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#rosewood").click(function () {
        $(".holcomb, .lunden, .maggie, .rosewood").hide("fast");
        $("button").hide("fast")
        $(".rosewood").slideDown(1500);
        $("button#rosewood").show("fast")
    });
});
</script>
```

I just need help with simplifying this script.

All that happens is, I have some links and when you click them a div (with a class) shows. Then a button also pops up beside the link, and then when you click it closes (obviously) or when you click another link it closes the currently opened div and opens the other div.

Comment: Are you using the same `id` on multiple elements? That's not valid HTML, you know

Comment: no, im using different id elements for each button, everything else is using classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to all of the elements you want to have this show/hide thing work on then you can do this all with:

```
var $allElements = $(".showHide");


$allElements.click(function () {
    $allElements.hide("fast");
    $(this).slideDown(1500);
    /* you'd have to add some logic here for the matching button...
       ...perhaps give it an ID matching the link with a suffix of '-button' 
       or something */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply better application of classes would make this code simpler, but working with what you have...

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(".holcomb, .lunden, .maggie, .rosewood").hide("slow");
        $("button").hide("fast");
    });

    $("a#holcomb, a#lunden, a#maggie, a#rosewood").click(function () {
       $(".holcomb, .lunden, .maggie, .rosewood").hide("fast");
       $("button").hide("fast");
       $("."+this.id).slideDown(1500);
       $("button#"+this.id).show("fast")
   });
});
```